# Why can´t I transfer app scores from an iPod to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I have an iPod running on iOS 5 and and iPhone running on iOS10. I backed up my iPhone to my computer (Mac OS) using iTunes. I made sure that the apps were on the Mobile Applications folder. I then connected the iPhone to the computer, opened iTunes and found the apps I wanted to install. A "Will Install" notice appeared next to the apps and I synced the iPhone. When the syncing was finished, the apps were installed on the iPhone, but the game progress was lost. Why are the games scored not transfered to the iPhone? Can they be transfered though iCloud?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit - In response to @fsb: This happens with all the games on the iPhone (Bravesmart, Cut the Rope, Where´s My Water, Angry Birds, etc.).  As for contacting the developers, I have not done so thus far.

Comment: Is this 1 specific game or all games?  Did you sign into the same iCloud account on both devices?  Have you contacted the developer(s) to see if the game supports what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Scores are not stored into the app, so the apps backed up into your iTunes doesn't have your scores.

In order to share scores between different devices, I think that developers are usually using iCloud Drive (only available since iOS 8) https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204230

But older games was using Game Center to share scores, so you will probably be able to share them through this one.
https://www.imore.com/game-center